# Emotion Detect on live screen

Tags: python, opencv, python-mss

Trying to build a system to detect emotion in online meeting using python.
I have created a deep learning model to detect emotions.

Using this code to view the screen

```
import time
import cv2
import mss
import numpy


with mss.mss() as sct:
    monitor = {"top": 0, "left": 0, "width": 1000, "height": 1000}
    
    while "Screen capturing":
        last_time = time.time()

        img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))

        cv2.imshow("OpenCV/Numpy normal", img)


        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Is there any way I can connect my model with this screen and see the emotions on this live screen?

My output should be face on the screen along with emotion text on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `img` variable to your model and get the emotions (as text) during inference. After that, it's a matter of updating the image by using OpenCV [putText](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-puttext-method/) and then displaying this updated image using imshow.

```
img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))
detected_emotion = inference(img)    # model infers emotion here

image = cv2.putText(img, 'detected_emotion', org=(50, 50), font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, fontScale=1, color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=2, cv2.LINE_AA)
 
cv2.imshow("OpenCV/Numpy normal", image)
```